# Mouse slows down, sticks, jumps, no clear pattern - related to Wacom tablet? Compiz?

Tags: 14.04, compiz, mouse, 64-bit, wacom

Sometimes the mouse pointer is nice and agile, and sometimes it slows down tremendously or sticks, taking a big sweeping motion just to get it the last centimeter so it passes over a field or button where i want it.  Sometimes it decided i've clicked when i haven't, other times i have to click 2 or 3 times.

The mouse is wireless and its batteries are good. I've tried with a different mouse but the problem persists. I also have a Wacom Bamboo tablet and i switch back and forth, partially just to try to keep working when it is annoying me this way. The tablet doesn't display this behaviour, only the mouse. I tried unplugging the tablet to see if it would help, it makes no difference.

The system is brand new and it is also a fresh install of 64-bit 14.04. This behaviour has happened with every install of Ubuntu, and also happened on my old system, which shared no components with this one other than the tablet and the hard drives. So I presume this has to do with the tablet. It is a Bamboo Capture Pen & Touch, CTH-470. I am a novice to Linux, I'm afraid. How should I go about fixing this?

Edit: After looking around a bit, in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/19869/364597) it talked about using System Monitor to find out what is using CPU resources. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/461889/364597) talked about compiz causing mouse lag. So I opened the system monitor, found compiz, and am checking what %CPU it is taking. I just moved the browser window and it jumped to 18%. As I'm typing it is fluctuating between 2 and 5%. I have a lot of browser tabs open right now, and a window with Blender in the background, partly in an effort to load up the system and find the issue. Just moving the mouse around is causing Compiz to spike at 6 to 8%.

Also, at the bottom of the comments on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/615601/364597), the asker mentions that moving the mouse to a 'super USB', which I took to be a USB 3.0 port, their mouse issues ceased. I have also done that. For a while that seemed to help, but now the mouse is once again sticking and jumping. There seems to be a correlation to how long the computer has been on, and how bad it is, and also it seems to get worse over or near buttons and fields. But then it works fine again for a while.

My system has a Haswell i7, 16 GB RAM and a GeForce GTX 960. It's built for graphics work, which makes this problem that much more annoying.

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3d' is`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1401 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 3966
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fba (rev a1)
```

Output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen stylus          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400d   id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser          id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad          id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft LifeCam                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.244494] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.244630] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.244811] pnp 00:05: [dma 0 disabled]
[    0.244835] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
[    0.245144] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
```

I am using a Microsoft mouse right now. An Acer mouse was previously connected to it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 ok, done

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 alright, done too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this issue was do to radio interference with my wireless mouse. I got a wired mouse, and for the last week I have had absolutely no problems. That's long enough for me to be sure that was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a proprietary video driver.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

and reboot.

Comment: Alright, that's done. But it didn't help. :-/  Even right after startup sweeping the mouse around shows considerable lag and jumping, and just now i had trouble clicking on a button in a dialog box because the mouse kept lagging and then overshooting. I was trying to check for updates in the software updater, but right now it can't download the repository info.