# How to close IntelliJ IDEA if it hung?

Tags: intellij

I can't close the IntelliJ IDEA when it hangs, how can I close it from the terminal?

P.S.: I think this question is different from "How to kill a unresponsive program from terminal?" because IntelliJ's process has name just 'java' so you can't really tell it apart by its name.

Comment: In the System Monitor application you can clearly see which process belongs to IntelliJ IDEA. It's the process that has the IntelliJ IDEA icon to the left of it. Under the circumstances this seems to be an easier way to close IntelliJ than closing it from the terminal.

Comment: I agree. But in the terminal you can't see it

Comment: It doesn't matter because IntelliJ is a GUI app, so you can easily open the System Monitor too instead of the terminal. I have a custom keyboard shortcut for quickly opening my System Monitor. Even though this comment is not an answer within the constraints of your question, it should be an answer anyway IMO because it's a much easier way to do it.

Comment: An easier way would be https://askubuntu.com/questions/19869/how-to-identify-and-kill-hanging-process-when-system-hangs-and-reacts-slowly-on – no terminal required like @karel suggests

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's running as a java process so you can use

```
killall java -9
```

(Warning! This command kills all java processes)

Source: [Intellij support forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206223969-How-to-close-IntelliJ-IDEA-if-it-hung-Linux-)

Comment: It would be safer to only kill java processes from IntelliJ's bundled JVM, e.g. `killall /opt/intellij/jre64/bin/java`. You can find the full path to a running IntelliJ's java process with `ps -eo command | grep java | awk '{ print $1 }'`.

Comment: This worked for me excellently. Thank you.

Comment: You should try `killall java` first

Answer (score 8):

You can list all processes with

```
ps aux
```

and you can search processes with

```
pgrep <process name>
```

Then you can kill the process you want with

```
sudo kill -KILL <pid>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux)

Comment: I would only add that `pgrep` returns only the PID, so if your search is too broad, you may see processes that are not the ones you're trying to kill.  I would rather do `ps aux | grep <search term>` so that you can see more details about the processes.